# Postgres: Querying multiple jsonb fields

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

Having a table with a column containing jsonb data, I want to query those data with multiple fields.
The jsonb structure looks like this:

```
{
  "https://example.tld/": 
  [
    {
      "content-length": 312,
      "path": "page.log",
      "redirect": null,
      "status": 200
    },
    {
      "content-length": 312,
      "path": "pages/",
      "redirect": null,
      "status": 200
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I want to query all log files with status 200, so I did

```
SELECT json_data -> 'path' AS path
FROM table
WHERE json_data->'status' = 200 AND json_data->'path' ILIKE '%.log%'
```

However, it does not work. The closest variant I get to work is if I cast the json content into text and search for log, but it returns the whole content.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE json_data::text ILIKE '%.log%'
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: (PostgreSQL) 10.12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the paths from the underlying array in JSON.  If so:

```
select rs.path
from t cross join
     jsonb_to_recordset(t.json -> 'https://example.tld/') rs(status int, path text)
 where rs.path ilike '%.log%' and rs.status = 200
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ee87c6cf91a0068ae68f2140f63ef096) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How can I make the query independent from a specific domain? Is there something like t.json->[0] possible? I mean to query the first array entry without specifying domain name like https://example.tld/.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i get "ERROR: cannot call jsonb_to_recordset on a non-array"

Comment: @nullpointr . . . (1) I would suggest that you ask a new question.  (2) The simplest method is to include the domain in the array, rather than having it be a *key*.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the top-level key name (`https://example.tld/` in this case) changes from row to row in your table, you will not be able to use a fixed path and will have to expand the object with `jsonb_each()` before expanding the array elements with `jsonb_array_elements()`.

```
with indat as ( select 1 as id, '{
  "https://example.tld/":
  [
    {
      "content-length": 312,
      "path": "page.log",
      "redirect": null,
      "status": 200
    },
    {
      "content-length": 312,
      "path": "pages/",
      "redirect": null,
      "status": 200
    }
  ]
}'::jsonb as json_data
)
select i.id, j.key, e.element
  from indat i
 cross join lateral jsonb_each(json_data) as j(key, value)
 cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(j.value) as e (element)
 where e->>'path' ilike '%.log%'
   and e->>'status' = '200';

 id |         key          |                                   element
----+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | https://example.tld/ | {"path": "page.log", "status": 200, "redirect": null, "content-length": 312}
(1 row)
```